# How can I select from stored procedures in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need help solving selecting from a procedure table from MySQL in Codelgniter and loading the data into Datatable. I am new to Codelgniter, for the past few days, I have been trying to solve this.

In my **Controller** I tried the following:

```
function get_vendors_sales_detail() {

     
        $customer = $this->input->get('customer') ? $this->input->get('custoproduct_codemer') : NULL;
        $start_date = $this->input->get('start_date') ? $this->input->get('start_date') : NULL;
        $end_date = $this->input->get('end_date') ? $this->input->get('end_date') : NULL;
        $user = $this->input->get('user') ? $this->input->get('user') : NULL;

        $this->load->library('datatables');
        $this->datatables
        ->select("sn, date, customer_name, product_name, product_code, total_items, unit_price  ")
        ->from('vendor03_product_sales');
        if ($this->session->userdata('store_id')) {
            $this->datatables->where('store_id', $this->session->userdata('store_id'));
        }
        $this->datatables->unset_column('id');
        if($customer) { $this->datatables->where('customer_name', $customer); }
        if($user) { $this->datatables->where('created_by', $user); }
        if($start_date) { $this->datatables->where('date >=', $start_date); }
        if($end_date) { $this->datatables->where('date <=', $end_date); }

        echo $this->datatables->generate();
        $this->page_construct('reports/vendors_sales_details', $this->data, $meta);
        

    }
```

But in my view, I am getting an error. I have tried making a search online but could not find what I need. I need help from Codelgniter experts.

Comment: can u share your error that you are getting in your view and you didn't used isset() while you are using ternary operator and i do find some mistake near if conditions

Comment: Is this, vendor03_product_sales, the stored procedure? Stored Procedures are executed with the CALL statement.

Comment: @J2112O Yes, it is.

Comment: @Modollarpo . Stored Procedures shouldn't be in the WHERE clause (in this case where() method). Have you tried to place the table name in the where() method that has the columns listed in the select() method?